# Check if Youtube video ID match else load a new video id

Tags: jquery, function, iframe, youtube-api, seek

I want to seek in youtube embed videos, but I have severals videos.

1. I launch Video-A on startup
2. I have a menu with 2 seek function
3. Link A seek on Video-A
4. Link B seek on Video-B

So I need to check which video is playing before to seek:
If video id match ==> seek
Else ==> load a new video in the player + seek (when new video is loaded and playing)

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var player;
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: 'JP9-lAYngi4',
            height: '405',
            width: '720',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1},
            events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        })

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
            if(event.data === 1) {          
                //alert('playing');
            }
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                var url = event.target.getVideoUrl();
                // "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzDS-Kfd5XQ&feature=..."
                var match = url.match(/[?&]v=([^&]+)/);
                // ["?v=gzDS-Kfd5XQ", "gzDS-Kfd5XQ"]
                var videoId = match[1];
                //alert(videoId)

                $('#linkok').click(function(){ 
                    if(videoId == "JP9-lAYngi4") {
                        //alert("same as onload:" + videoId);
                        player.loadVideoById("x9Us_jMV8hA");
                        //alert("new video loaded: x9Us_jMV8hA")
                    } 
                    else {
                        alert("not the same:" + videoId)
                    }                           
                });
            };
        };
    };
</script>
```

My video div and menu:

```
<div id="video"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="player.playVideo();player.seekTo(60);">ON CLICK SEEKTO 60s in Video-A</a><br>
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="player.playVideo();player.seekTo(120);">ON CLICK SEEKTO 120s in Video-B</a><br>
```

My code is not well done, and not really working as I was expecting
Can you please help me make better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bala: Not sure to get what you're saying... (sorry I'm not a programer, I just copy paste and mix codes allready available)

Comment: I think I get what you say, but How I'm I supposed to do then?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like that, **but please let me know how to simplify this code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var videoId;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var player;
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: 'joITmEr4SjY',
            height: '405',
            width: '720',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1},
            events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        });

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
            if(event.data === 1) {          
                //alert('playing');
            }
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                var url = event.target.getVideoUrl();
                // "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzDS-Kfd5XQ&feature=..."
                var match = url.match(/[?&]v=([^&]+)/);
                // ["?v=gzDS-Kfd5XQ", "gzDS-Kfd5XQ"]
                videoId = match[1];
            }

        };
        $('#link01').click(function(){ 
            if(videoId == "joITmEr4SjY") {
                alert("Good Video: " + videoId);
                player.seekTo(120);
            }
            else {
                alert("Wrong Video: " + videoId)
                player.loadVideoById("joITmEr4SjY");
                player.seekTo(120);
            }                           
        });
        $('#link02').click(function(){ 
            if(videoId == "l9dpjN3Mwps") {
                alert("Good Video: " + videoId);
                player.seekTo(240);
            }
            else {
                alert("Wrong Video: " + videoId)
                player.loadVideoById("l9dpjN3Mwps");
                player.seekTo(240);
            }                           
        });
    };
</script>
```